# How do I write a sql query in vba to filter data while importing an excel file?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an excel file (raw data) which I have to import to another excel file (visualization interface). But, before importing the raw data file, I have to filter out the data of some columns. Can I write an sql query within my import file vba code?
For instance, I want to filter out the blank values from one column and see only numbers greater than 10 from another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. In your Visualization interface file (viz.xls) create a new module and add the

> Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library

Using Tools >> References

The following code will get you in the ballpark:

```
Sub getFromRawData()
    Dim rawFile As String

    Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim adoRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    'The xlsx file to treat as a database
    rawFile = "c:\myFolder\myrawdatafile.xlsx"

    'Open a connection to the workbook
    adoConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & rawFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"

    'Write the SQL necessary to get the data you want (assuming Sheet1 and making up column names, which will be the first row of the sheet by default)
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [onecolumn] IS NOT NULL AND [anotherColumn] > 10;"

    'Now we open up our recordset using the connection and the sql statement
    adoRS.Open strSQL, adoConn

    'Last, we dump the results in this viz sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheet1.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset adoRS

    'If you want the header row, you'll have to get that from the recordset:
    Dim adoField As ADODB.Field
    Dim intHdrCol

    'initial column to start writing header
    intHdrCol = 1

    'loop through the fields in the recordset and write the column
    For Each adoField In adoRS.Fields
        Sheet1.Cells(1, intHdrCol).Value = adoField.Name
        intHdrCol = intHdrCol + 1
    Next adoField


    'Close the connection
    adoRS.Close
    adoConn.Close

End Sub
```

Depending on your version of Excel you'll have to fiddle with that Connection String. The SQL statement will have to modified as well, obviously.. but with some tinkering this thing is ready to rock and roll.

Comment: NB: you should have a much more recent version of ActiveX library by now (like 6 or 6.1).